# How to transfer items between characters?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

Is there a way to transfer items between my characters in Dungeon Siege 3?

I've been searching what seems high and low for any info...

1. Can I transfer items between my characters (protagonist, companion (AI))?
2. If not, is there a general rule to who picks up the drop?
3. If there isn't, how can I influence who gets the drop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dungeon Siege 3 uses a single shared inventory.

It doesn't matter who picks up an item, it goes into the inventory.  While playing single-player and in the equipping menu, press `Y` to switch characters.  While playing two-player, each player can access their own equipping menu.

Items are equip-able by certain characters.  For example, if a weapon drops, that weapon will show the portrait of a character.  Only that character may equip it, but anyone may pick it up.

Comment: I think the edits got a little out of hand.. The same goes for the PS3 version of the game, correct?

Comment: Yes.  PS3 players would press triangle to switch characters in the equipping menu.